# how to detect polygons within other (many) polygons in postgis

Tags: postgis, cartodb

I have two datasets: 1. ZipCodes and 2. Neighborhoods (think of them as like counties).

I want to join each neighborhood with which zipcodes cover it. Most neighborhoods will only be within one zipcode, but in some cases neighborhoods will straddle two. So for example:

Neighborhood 1 is inside 20001
Neighborhood 2 is inside 20002
Neighborhood 3 is inside 20001,20002

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT name, zipcode  
FROM    
neighborhood_names nn, dc_zipcode_boundries dzb
WHERE ST_Intersects(nn.the_geom, dzb.the_geom);
```

Note: Updated to within based on comments, now getting an answer for each neighborhood but still not able to get the Array function to respond as expected.

Comment: You are not missing anything as such, though you might wants to use ST_Intersects, which will also pick up those zip codes that straddle a border. If you want one row of output for each neighbourhood, then you can use the array_agg function, along with GROUP by names, which will return something like 3, [20001, 20002] for your 3rd example row, rather than two rows.

Comment: so i tried this:
<br>
select nn.the_geom_webmercator, name, string_Agg(zipcode, ',') as zipcodeArr from
<br>
neighborhood_names nn, dc_zipcode_boundries dzb
where ST_Intersects(nn.the_geom,dzb.the_geom)
<br>

and generally got errros: column "nn.the_geom_webmercator" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function


what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. thanks to the help from John. My statement needed a group by (whcih is what the error said, just needed some time to digest before it clicked).

the snippet below worked for anyone following

```
SELECT name, array_to_string(array_agg(zipcode), ',') 
FROM    
neighborhood_names nn, dc_zipcode_boundries dzb
WHERE ST_Intersects(nn.the_geom, dzb.the_geom)
group by name
```